# Looking for an option on Artifactory Pro to create a dashboard for Download Metrics

Tags: download, artifactory, dashboard, metrics

We are looking for an option in Artifactory Pro edition, where want to make a central dashboard for downloaded artifacts. Currently the each artifacts has count for # of downloads but we want to extend it more -

1. Number of downloads
2. Who downloaded it
3. from where its downloaded

Dashboard with filter criteria. Please help if anybody has build this type capability. I know probably we can use a plugin for this getting metrics and storing it to somewhere else. But we are looking for option provided by JFrog Artifactory.

Comment: What version of Artifactory are you using? Are you familiar with the Package View - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Package+Management ?

Comment: Artifactory Pro - 6.3.3, The Package Management -> Package View options are disabled for me. Is it wrongly configured/permission issue or license restriction.

Comment: It's the version you're on. It's available from Artifactory v7

Answer (score 0):

Package view is part of the Platform versions (Artifactory 7.x and above): https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Package+Management
I suggest you upgrade as this is pretty much what you need.

On your current version there isn't such dashboard, but you can gather the information easily using the Artifactory Query Language: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Languagea

Answer (score 0):

There is no metrics dashboard provided by Jfrog out of the box that would fit this need.

As mentioned by Angello you need to **scrape** the metrics yourself using the AQL or using different APIs provided by Jfrog then use that data to post onto a dashboard custom made for your usecase.